# Gradle build fails on jenkins after upgrade

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I have a large application which uses gradle for its build, and jenkins for CI.
I upgraded gradle wrapper from version 2.4 to 3.4 recently. Every thing is ok in my development boxes, but 3 of test cases fail on the Jenkins box with NPE.
The NPE is caused by the fact that some records are not found in database. The records supposed to be inserted by dbunit.
We have thousands of test cases, following the same dbunit, pattern. None of them fail.
Does any one is aware of any change betwee gradle 2.4. to 3.4 that might cause this issue.

Comment: Can you share snippets of code?

Comment: Well, I cannot really narrow it down to a representable piece of code. I thought someone would know of something that is changed between these versions that might help me debug it.